# Is there a way to store/retrieve a pointer (that is pointing to a memory location) inside a file?

Tags: c++

I am storing records in a file using classes. And I need to create a seperate index file which stores a key (unique for each record) and a corresponding address location pointing to the records in order to reduce access time. I thought a pointer can be made to point to the class object. But how can I read/write a pointer from and to a file?

Comment: You can, but that makes no sense as next time when you read the pointer, more than likely the pointers are invalid. You need to save the data. Can you provide more detail on what you want to archive?

Comment: Memory locations can vary between invocations of running the program, and so are not a stable way of referring to the objects. Instead, use a hash table or similar structure. The index on disk could refer to the offset within the file (look up `ftell()` for example) but you would need to regenerate the index file whenever the main file changed too. Some more info on what you're trying to achieve would help.

Comment: @Tony The project is basically to implement the file structures concepts like I'm trying to implement the concept of indexing to retrieve data stored in files faster by avoiding search on the entire file and searching only a smaller file that has unique keys for each record then the corresponding address directly points to where the complete record is stored.

Comment: The concept you're looking for is "serialization".

Comment: Save all the data in the data file, and save the sorted 'key' in the index file. record the location of each record along with the key.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to manage your memory allocation yourself. In the simplest approach (illustrative, not recommended), you'd just allocate a block of memory on the heap big enough for all your records, then save your pointers in file as offsets from the beginning of that block (and, when reading, convert the offsets back to actual pointers).

Or perhaps store the records in a file and then record file positions (file offsets) instead of pointers for quick access via seek.

Comment: use a hashmap ftw.

Comment: @Swordfish, Well, sure. But at this level of query, the simplest paradigm is a good first step toward progress.

Comment: Thanks but nothing seems to work for reading/writing pointers to/from a file. Like I've come to believe pointers can't be stored in a seperate file and even if they are then they don't behave as pointers when they're retrieved.

Comment: @SivaSubramanian: you're conceptually correct. Pointers can't be stored in a file. You can store the bits (i.e., treat the pointer as an integer of the appropriate length), but that's really not useful. You need to manage the conversion of the pointer from a pointer to memory to some representation of a handle to the data it points to, and then convert it from that handle to a pointer (to the new location of that info -- wherever it landed when you read the info in) when you you read the handle in.

Answer (score 0):

> I thought a pointer can be made to point to the class object.

Correct. A pointer can point to a class object.

> But how can I read/write a pointer from and to a file?

You can reinterpret a data pointer as `std::uintptr_t`, which is an integer type. You can write the integer into a file.

In converse, the integer can be read from a file, and reinterpreted as a pointer.

Note that a pointer value can become invalid if the pointed object ceases to exist. No object can exists between multiple executions of a program, so the stored pointer value can stay valid only during the execution where it was written.

---

> a smaller file that has unique keys for each record then the corresponding address directly points to where the complete record is stored.

So, you want to "point" to a position in a file. That is not an "object". A pointer cannot point to a position in a file.

It seems like what you need is simply an integer: The offset of the first byte of the record in the file. So, if you write the record in the offset 12345, then you can "point" to that offset with the integer 12345.